# Azure Blob Storage Client Side Upload

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

For my node js project, I used an AWS S3 bucket and uploaded files from the front end using the AWS SDK.

Similarly, My file storage now needs to be migrated to **Azure Blob Storage**

**Is there a way to upload directly to Azure Blob Storage from the client side?**

Using Stack: Node Js (Javascript with EJS as Template engine)

I tried to build a bundle using **browserify** by passing the BlobServiceClient like this,

```
var { BlobServiceClient } = require("@azure/storage-blob");
window.BlobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient;
```

But its showing errors like `TypeError: BlobServiceClient is not a constructor`

In the end, I would like to replace the S3 bucket upload functions with Azure blob storage functions, and I would like to require the BlobServiceClient from "@azure/storage-blob" so I don't have to change much code on the front end.

Please help with a solution to integrate the azure storage npm package into the browser.

Answer (score 2):

***I tried in my environment and successfully uploaded file in Azure blob storage using  browser.***

Before starting you need to install two packages.

```
1.npm install @azure/storage-blob
2.npm install parcel
```

**Index.js**

```
const { BlobServiceClient } = require("@azure/storage-blob"); 
const  selectButton = document.getElementById("select-button");
const  fileInput = document.getElementById("file-input");
const  blobSasUrl = "<your sas url >";

const  blobServiceClient = new  BlobServiceClient(blobSasUrl);
const  containerName = "test";
const  containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
const  uploadFiles = async () => {
try {
const  promises = [];
for (const  file  of  fileInput.files) {
const  blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(file.name);
promises.push(blockBlobClient.uploadData(file));
}
await  Promise.all(promises);
alert("Done.");
}
catch (error) {
alert(error.message);
}
}
selectButton.addEventListener("click", () =>  fileInput.click());

fileInput.addEventListener("change", uploadFiles);
```

**Index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE  html>

<html>
<body>

<button  id="select-button">Select and upload files</button>

<input  type="file"  id="file-input"  multiple  style="display: none;"  />

<script  type="module"  src="index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**package.json**

```
{

"name": "blob-quickstart-v12",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
"start": "parcel ./index.html"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"browserslist": [
"last 1 Edge version",
"last 1 Chrome version",
"last 1 Firefox version",
"last 1 safari version",
"last 1 webkit version"
],
"dependencies": {
"@azure/storage-blob": "^12.12.0",
 "parcel": "^2.8.0"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
 "buffer": "^5.7.1"}
 }
```

You can get the **`Blob SAS-URL`** by checking below image.

[image]

**Console:**

[image]

**Browser:**

I copied the **`Url`** and pasted in browser it worked.

[image]

After uploading it reflects done in browser.

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[Get started with Azure Blob Storage and JavaScript - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-javascript-get-started)

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, This method works fine. However, In my case, I am running a Node Js (Express) project. Since I am not using Parcel to run my project, and the require function does not support in the front end, how can I integrate the Azure bundle/SDK into my project?

Answer (score 1):

> To use this client library in the browser, first you need to use a bundler. For details on how to do this, please refer to our [bundling documentation](https://aka.ms/AzureSDKBundling)

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/main/sdk/storage/storage-blob/README.md?plain=1#L99